# How to change the wallpaper on page while hitting the hyperlink with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the div section on my page that is responsible for the whole background, the css looks like this:

```
#section2{
   background-image: url(img/first.jpg);
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-size: cover;
   z-index: 1;
}
```

later on my webpage I have the following menu items:

```
<div class="section" id="section2">
   <ul id="navlist">
    <li><a href="#" class="whatsthat">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="howitworks">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="howmuch">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="whyexists">Four</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

And it works like this, that every time when I hit the menu item above, the javascript is called:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".howitworksdiv, .howmuchdiv, .whyexistsdiv").hide();

    $(".whatsthat, .howitworks, .howmuch, .whyexists").bind("click", function () {

      $(".whatsthatdiv, .howitworksdiv, .howmuchdiv, .whyexistsdiv").hide();        

      if ($(this).attr("class") == "whatsthat")
      {
        $(".whatsthatdiv").fadeIn();
      }
      else if ($(this).attr("class") == "howitworks")
      { 
        $(".howitworksdiv").fadeIn();

      }
      else if ($(this).attr("class") == "howmuch")
      { 
        $(".howmuchdiv").fadeIn();
        $('#stand-sentence').addClass('active');
      }
      else if ($(this).attr("class") == "whyexists")
      { 
        $(".whyexistsdiv").fadeIn();
      }
    });

});
```

and it's made due to show/hide different panel in the same place. I would like to achieve a possibility of showing different background for each panel, for example when user chooses whyexists, then it could set up `background-image: url(img/fourth.jpg);`, etc.
How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

`$('#section2').css({'background-image': 'url(img/fourth.jpg)'});`

Answer (score 0):

Just change `#section2`'s background with jQuery `css()`:

```
$('#section2').css('background-image','url("blah.jpg")');
```

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L0agu0u8/)

Answer (score 0):

use `$().css(property, value)`

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".howitworksdiv, .howmuchdiv, .whyexistsdiv").hide();

    $(".whatsthat, .howitworks, .howmuch, .whyexists").bind("click", function () {

      $(".whatsthatdiv, .howitworksdiv, .howmuchdiv, .whyexistsdiv").hide();        

      if ($(this).attr("class") == "whatsthat")
      {
        $(".whatsthatdiv").fadeIn();
        $('#section2').css('background-image','url("whatsthat.jpg")');
      }
      else if ($(this).attr("class") == "howitworks")
      { 
        $(".howitworksdiv").fadeIn();
        $('#section2').css('background-image','url("howitworks.jpg")');

      }
      else if ($(this).attr("class") == "howmuch")
      { 
        $(".howmuchdiv").fadeIn();
        $('#stand-sentence').addClass('active');
        $('#section2').css('background-image','url("howmuch.jpg")');
      }
      else if ($(this).attr("class") == "whyexists")
      { 
        $(".whyexistsdiv").fadeIn();
        $('#section2').css('background-image','url("whyexists.jpg")');
      }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you could handle this:

Create a class for each background image, and apply it to the desired element in the click handler:

```
.bg1 {
  background-image: url(/path/to/some/background.jpg);
}
.bg2 {
  background-image: url(/path/to/some/other/background.jpg);
}
```

And within your jQuery click handler:

```
$element.addClass("bg1");
$anotherElement.addClass("bg2");
```

or you could modify the inline css directly:

```
$element.css("background-image", "url(/path/to/some/background.jpg)");
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It feels as though you've overcomplicated your JavaScript by quite a lot. By the way, I believe that jQuery's .bind() is out of favor these days. I thought it had actually been deprecated, but I guess it hasn't been yet.

Anyway, I would do something like this. I made some assumptions, obviously, about your HTML structure.

```
    $('#navlist').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
        var linkClass = $(this).attr('class'),
            requestedSection = $('#' + linkClass + 'div');
        requestedSection.siblings().fadeOut();
        requestedSection.fadeIn();
        $('body').css('background-image', '/images/backgrounds/' + linkClass + '.jpg');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```